# D3.js V4 Forced Directed Graph Zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I'm new to D3 and am simply experimenting with its capabilities. Forgive me if this has already been covered but I cannot seem to find a way to implement zoom onto my D3.js v4 forced-directed graph. My code is as below.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
 stroke: #999;
 stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<div class="centre jumbotron">
 <h1> Title </h1>
  <h2>
   This is the home page
  </h2>
</div>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
width = +svg.attr("width"),
height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("network_data#all", function(error, graph) {
 if (error) throw error;

 var link = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

 var node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));

 node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

 simulation
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .on("tick", ticked);

 simulation.force("link")
  .links(graph.links);

 function ticked() {
  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
   }
  });

 function dragstarted(d) {
   if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
   d.fx = d.x;
   d.fy = d.y;
 }

 function dragged(d) {
   d.fx = d3.event.x;
   d.fy = d3.event.y;
 }

 function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
   d.fx = null;
   d.fy = null;
 }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty straight-forward and demonstrated [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4e3925cdc804db257a86fdef3a032a45).  It's doesn't really matter that you have a force-simulation, the steps are the same.

Here's it integrated into you sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .links line {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: 0.6;
  }
  
  .nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
</style>
<div class="centre jumbotron">
 <h1> Title </h1>
  <h2>
   This is the home page
  </h2>
</div>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");
    
  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .call(d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
      .on("zoom", zoomed));

  var g = svg.append("g");

  function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  }

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/6e520635-d35c-11e6-b16a-6b255c15b1a3", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var link = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
      });

    var node = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.group);
      })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

    node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });

    simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });

      node
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y;
        });
    }
  });

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I have implimented the changes you have stated however my graph still does not seem to zoom. Inspecting the page elements it appears that the 'rect' property does transform however the graph appears not be within the same propety.

Comment: @FayeMatthews, can you reproduce the issue in a plunker, jsFiddle or stacksnippet?  As you can see in my stacksnippet above, my code does indeed work integrated into the sample code you showed.  It's now on you to reproduce your issue.

Comment: No worries, found the problem, your code worked fine for me @Mark. Thank you very much :)